# What is the reason why a nested generic with a covariant type param within a generic with an invariant type parameter does not compile?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-errors, covariance

Here's some code to accompany my question:

```
interface IFirmEntity { }
interface IClient : IFirmEntity { }

class Repository
{
    public Task<ReadOnlyCollection<IClient>> GetClientsAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<IClient> GetClients()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now, if I write the following code, I get the error described below that:

```
var repo = new Repository();

// works b/c of covariance on IReadOnlyCollection<T>
IReadOnlyCollection<IFirmEntity> a1 = repo.GetClients();

// does not work b/c of invariance of Task<T>
Task<IReadOnlyCollection<IFirmEntity>> a2 = repo.GetClientsAsync();
```

> (CS0029) Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>   to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'

So, where `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is covariant on `T` and `Task<T>` is invariant on `T`, `Task<IReadOnlyCollection<IFirmEntity>>` does not work even though it seems like it should.

What is the technical reason why nested generics combined with covariance doesn't compile?

---

Also, as a side note, the code below works just fine, but, unless I'm understanding it wrong, I'm assuming the compiler is smart enough to evaluate the covariance used within the async/await state machine:

```
var mech = new SomeMechanism();

// this works just fine.
Task<IReadOnlyCollection<IFirmEntity>> a3 = 
    mech.DoAsync(async () => await repo.GetClientsAsync()); // No error.

class SomeMechanism
{
    public Task DoAsync(Func<Task<IReadOnlyCollection<IFirmEntity>>> someOperation) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: `Task<T>` is a class so is invariant, the nested generic types aren't relevant.

Comment: Then why does it work in the async/await case?

Comment: And I thought variance applied to generic *type params*, not to the generics themselves.

Comment: Because async lifts values of type `T` into `Task<T>` and as your example shows you can assign a `ReadOnlyCollection<IClient>` to a `ReadOnlyCollection<IFirmEntity>`

Comment: So basically the way I stated it was correct, that the compiler recognizes the acceptable covariance used within the block while interpreting that block as an async/await state machine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "covariance of the block" - the covariance of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` means you can assign a `ReadOnlyCollection<IClient>` `ReadOnlyCollection<IFirmEntity>`, but your example would work the same with `Task<string>` and `Task<object>`.